# remove specific text from html page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an automated `<li>` list created in my page with some text as link:

```
<ul class="continents">
   <li class="link"><a href="#">hotels in USA</a></li>
   <li class="link"><a href="#">hotels in Europe</a></li>
   <li class="link"><a href="#">hotels in Asia</a></li>
   <li class="link"><a href="#">hotels in Africa</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove only the `"hotels in "` from the links. can I do it with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [.text( function(index, text) )](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text)

[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4WpD/1)</kbd>

```
$('.continents a').text(function (_, old){
    return old.replace('hotels in ', '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(".continents li>a").each(function () {


   console.log($(this).html().replace('hotels', ''));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n9Wf6/1/)